# You have an error in your SQL syntax...?

Tags: php, mysql

//Can anyone tell me where is the error in the below sql query.

```
$sql = "insert into $table ($columns) values ($values)";
```

/Its gives me this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version >for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: you should show us the string after inserting values... so use `echo $sql` after this line

Comment: Most likely an sql injection issue.

Comment: //this is the function which make insertion in database
public function insert($data, $table) {
  $columns = "";
  $values = "";
  foreach ($data as $column=>$value) {
   $columns .= ($columns == "") ? "" : ", ";
   $columns .= $column; 
   $values .= ($values == "") ? "" : ", "; 
   $values .= $value; 
  }
  $sql = "insert into ".$table." (".$columns.") values (".$values.")";
  mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
  return mysql_insert_id();
 }

Comment: you start `$columns` and `$values` with a semicolon, your algorithm is wrong, not the sql statement. btw edit your post, not comment the code

Comment: Sorry for commenting the code. But can u tell me the right algorithm. What should i do to eliminate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to check if there is no starting and trailing comma's in the `$columns` or `$values` variables. 
Plus, just to be sure, put appropriate quotes around the columns and values individually.

```
public function insert($data, $table) { 
$columns = ""; 
$values = ""; 

foreach ($data as $column=>$value) 
{
     $columns .= "`" . $column . "`, ";
     $values .=  "'" . $value . "', ";
 }

 $columns = substr($columns, 0, strlen($columns)-2);
 $values = substr($values, 0, strlen($values)-2);
 $sql = "insert into ".$table." (".$columns.") values (".$values.")"; mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); return mysql_insert_id(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ` backticks for MYSQL reserved words. Your query should be as follows.

```
$sql = "insert into `$table` (`$columns`) values (`$values`)";
```

Comment: And what happens when `$columns` and `$values` contain more then 1 column or value?

Comment: Now it gives me this error( Unknown column 'username, password, email, joinDate' in 'field list'")